# springboot microservice writing to azure databrick

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-databricks

I'm new to Azure and Azure DataBricks.

Trying to write a Java SpringBoot microservice that connects to Azure DataBricks to upload files. I have the following in application.properties file:

```
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.profile.tenant-id=....
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.credential.client-id=....
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.credential.client-secret=...
```

Access to the microservice endpoint does not require authentication/authorization. I'm having issues with getting the azure active directory working.

I have the following WebClient initialized

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager oAuth2AuthorizedClientManager) {
        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction function =
                new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(oAuth2AuthorizedClientManager);
        return WebClient.builder()
                .apply(function.oauth2Configuration())
                .build();
    }

}
```

I'm writing the following code for WebClient to access the DataBrick endpoint:

```
@Getter
public class AzureCreate {
    private String path;
    private boolean overwrite;

    // uriPrefix = "/FileStore/files"
    // uriSuffix = "test.txt"
    public AzureCreate(String uriPrefix, String uriSuffix, boolean overwrite) {
        path = uriPrefix + "//" + uriSuffix;
        this.overwrite = overwrite;
    }
}
...

    @Autowired
    private WebClient webClient;
    ...
    // machineURL = "https://ABCXYZ..azuredatabricks.net"
    // createSuffix = "/api/2.0/dbfs/create"
    URI createURI = URI.create(azureAccess.getMachineURL() + azureAccess.getCreateSuffix());
    WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec post = webClient.post();
    post.body(BodyInserters.fromValue(azureCreate));
    post.uri(createURI);

    String response = post.retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();
```

On the "post.retrieve()" method call an exception is thrown w/ the following message:

```
401 Unauthorized from POST https://ABCXYZ..azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/dbfs/create
```

Not sure how to configure microservice correctly and any of the Azure calls. Tried following

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-msal-java-samples/ms-identity-java-spring-tutorial/

but has not proven any luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,Jim

Comment: you need to add header that specify authentication token: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/

Comment: Thank you Alex. It worked. Your link mentions two ways to do this. I chose the "Authentication using Azure Databricks personal access tokens" one. Thus the only thing I had to do was add ```post.header("Authorization","Bearer dapi......")``` before my post.uri(createURI) call in the original post. HUGE APPRECIATION of your knowledge!!!

Comment: it can work with AAD token as well

Comment: Thanks again Alex. I'll look into this too. I'm now off implementing a blob storage solution too. Still trying to get my head wrapped around this authentication/authorization stuff.